# R function: run_matlab_script

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to run matlab script in R and I found a function matlabr::run_matlab_script()

However, I don't know how to use it. I already tried some matlab scripts but it doesn't run.

This is the code.

```
run_matlab_script('<matlabscript name>.m')
```

And this is the Console.

```
Command run is:
matlab.exe -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -nodisplay -r  "try, run('<matlabscript name>.m'); catch err, disp(err.message); exit(1); end; exit(0);"
[1] 1
```

There is no matlab script Error.

Comment: Can you run the script locally with those parameters?

Comment: I just put other parameters as default. But I couldn't find any examples of this function so I am not sure wheter other parameters are needed or not

Comment: @DaKyoungLee that is not the question. The question is: Can you open a windows/linux console, and run the parameters after "Command run is:" there?